# Xamarin.Forms with Prism not building in Visual Studio 2017 15.7.2

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017, prism

I have a Xamarin.Forms with Prism MVVM, having build problem in Visual Studio 2017 15.7.2.

This project was created in Visual Studio 2017 15.6.2, with Prism template, and was working perfectly.

I decided to update my IDE from 15.6.2 to 15.7.2, and my project stops working, getting the error below:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Your project is not referencing the "MonoAndroid,Version=v8.1" framework. Add a reference to "MonoAndroid,Version=v8.1" in the "frameworks" section of your project.json, and then re-run NuGet restore.    AppPrivateCard.Android          

A Xamarin.Forms project do not have project.json file, as suggested by the error message, and I already modified the target Android version to Android 27 version (Android Oreo 8.1), but the error persists.
```

I have already update Xamarin.Forms to 3.0.0.482510 and nothing.

But, if I create a Xamarin project without Prism, using VS 2017 15.7.2, and update all references, it builds without this error. So, I think the problem is the Prism template.

One option for me is to downgrade the VS 2017, but I would rather not.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Have you enable `Auto Install Android SDKs` in vs? To enable this feature, go to Tools > Options > Xamarin > Android Settings > Auto Install Android SDKs. You could refer to this [link](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/330723/#Comment_330723) for more information.

Comment: @Olivertech I am having slight similar issues after an upgrade. Did you get any where on this? My logs and try/catch around the problem are showing very little other than an InvalidCastException so I'm not sure it's the same problem which you're having.

Comment: I have the same problem... @Chuck, Olivertech has problem with compilation, not with exception on runtime.

Comment: @mersey what version of Xamarin forms are you using? I was on Xamarin Forms 2.4.0.7486. Upgrading from Xamarin Forms 2.4.0.74863 to 2.5.1.444934 fixed my problem. But I won't be able to update to Xamarin Forms 3 yet, as it has created compatibility bugs with the Telerik API.

Comment: @Chucky after I update Visual Studio I don't have compilation error anymore. Not I can compile my Xamarin app without any problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem.

Reason: file obj/project.assets.json target "MonoAndroid,Version=v7.1" when my project target android version 8.1

I resolved it by:

1. Right click Android project => Properties => Application => Compile
   using Android version => Android 7.1
2. Clean and Build project => build success, and restart IDE.
3. Right click Android project => Properties => Application => Compile
   using Android version => Android 8.1
4. Clean and Build project => build success

File obj/project.assets.json updated to "MonoAndroid,Version=v8.1"